# Running JS Code on Multiple Websites Quickly

Tags: javascript

I wish to run some JS code to verify some settings on multiple subpages of a website. If I run this JS code in the console on developer tools in Chrome, it works fine. However, I have many websites that I want to run this on and I want the output to be printed to me at once (namely if any sites have wrong settings and which ones they are). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Googlr stuff called `SharedWorkers`, I think it can help

Comment: This kind of question is generally out of scope for StackOverflow. However what you've described is pretty much exactly what [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) was built for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider writing the code in a persistent [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) instead of the console. (You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).) You can configure the userscript to run on whichever domains you need by setting `@include` directives in the metadata block. When a page the userscript is enabled is loaded by the browser, the userscript's code will run automatically. Once a page is processed, call [`GM_setValue`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) to save the results as an item in an array. (This data can be retrieved cross-domain!)

Once a page is processed, go onto the next page by assigning to `window.location.href`, such that the userscript is enabled on the new href as well. On that page, retrieve the value stored previously, process the current page, push the results for the new page to the array, then go onto the next page using the same method.

At the end, you can retrieve the values stored, analyze them as you need, and display the results.